# MIPS array not storing correct value

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a byte array with a size of 32. I am trying to find palindromes 1 to x in decimal and binary form. Many of my zeros in the array I use to store the array are ones for some reason. I have an array where I store the remainders of the integer when dividing by 2 and then afterwards store the reverse of the array in another array to compare. In the register I can clearly see that my register is 0 and the program calls lb for the array but when I print the array later on the 0 is turned into a 1. Here is the code.

```
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter value of n (in base 10): "
prompt2: .asciiz "Pairs of palindromic numbers from 1 through " 
error1: .asciiz "Please enter in a positive number " 
newLine: .asciiz "\n"
tab: .asciiz "\t"
array: .byte 32
array2: .byte 32
.text
main:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt1
    syscall                 # prompt user to enter value
    
    li $v0, 5
    syscall                 # user input
    
    move $t0, $v0               # $t0 = user integer (in decimal)
    bltz $t0, error             # if less than zero, jump to error
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newLine
    syscall                 #print new line
    li $t1, 1               #setting $t1 to 1 so the while loop starts at 1
while:
    bgt $t1, $t0, exit          #branch if the temp integer is equal to user integer
    li $t3, 1               #set $t3 to 1. This will be used for true or false 
    li $a1, 10              #set $a1 to base 10
    move $a2, $t1               #set $a2 as a clone of $t1 to modify
    jal isPalindrome            #jump to isPalindrome
    
    li $a1, 2               #set $a2 to base 2
    move $a2, $t1               #set $a1 as a clone of $t1 to modify
    jal isPalindrome            #jump to isPalindrome
    
    jal print
    addi $t1, $t1, 1            # add 1 to $t1
    j while
exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall                 #close program
error:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, error1
    syscall                 #print error message
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newLine
    syscall                 #print new line
    
    j main                  #jump to main
isPalindrome:
    beq $a1, 10, checkDec           #branch to toDecArray if base is 10
    beq $a1, 2, checkBin            #branch to toBinArray if base is 2
    li $t4, 0               #set $t4 to 0
    move $a2, $t5               #set $a2 equal to $t5
    jr $ra
checkDec:
    li $t5, 10              #set $t5 = 10
    li $a1, 0               #set to 0 to prevent infinite loop
    li $t7, 0               #set $t7 = 0
    loop2:          
        div $a2, $t5            #divide $a2 by $t5
        mflo $a2            # $a2 = quotient
        mfhi $t4            # $t4 = remainder
        mul $t7, $t7, $t5       # multiply $t7 by $t5 
        add $t7, $t7, $t4       # add $t4 to $t7
        bgtz $a2, loop2         #jump to loop2 if greater than 0
    bne $t7, $t1, notEqual
    j isPalindrome
checkBin:
    li $t6, 2               #setting $t6 to the base
    li $a1, 0               #setting $a1 = 0 so it doesn't also go through binArray again
    addi $t5, $zero, 0          #set $t5 = 0
    la $a3, array               #set $a3 to memory address of arrayt
    loop3:  
        div $a2, $t6            # divide $a2 by base
        mflo $a2            # $a2 = quotient
        mfhi $t4            # $t4 = remainder
        sb $t4, 0($a3)          #put $t4 into decArray binArray
        addi $a3, $a3, 1        #add 1 to t5
        bgtz $a2, loop3         #jump to loop if greater than 0
    subi $a3, $a3, 1            #subtract 1 from $a3 to prevent it from going out of bounds
    la $t4, array2              #load address from array 2 into $t4
    li $t6, 0               #load 0 into $t6 to use as counter
    la $s0, array
    reverse:                #loop to walk backwards and forwards in the array to see if they are the same 
        lb $t5, 0($a3)          #load byte from array into $t5
        subi $a3, $a3, 1        #subract a byte from $a3
        sb $t5, 0($t4)          #save byte into array2
        addi $t4, $t4, 1        #add a byte to $t4
        addi $t6, $t6, 1        #add a byte into $t5
        bge $a3, $s0, reverse       #branch back to reverse if the array is not equal to zero
    la $a3, array           
    la $t4, array2              #reinitialize $a3 as array and $t4 as array2 to start at beginning
    move $s0, $t6               #copy counter to print later
    checkEquality:
        lb $t5, 0($a3)
        lb $t7, 0($t4)
        bne $t5, $t7, notEqual
        subi $t6, $t6, 1
        bgez $t6, checkEquality
    j isPalindrome
        
        
notEqual:
    li $t3, 0               #set $t3 = 0
    jr $ra                  #jump to $ra
print:
    beqz $t3, leave
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t1
    syscall                 #print decimal form
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, tab
    syscall                 #print spaces
    
    addi $t5, $zero, 0          #set $t5 = 0
    la $a3, array
    printArray:
        lb $t6, 0($a3)          #load word from adress
    
        li $v0, 1
        move $a0, $t6       
        syscall             #print element from array
        
        addi $a3, $a3, 1        #add 1 to memory address
        addi $t5, $t5, 1        #add 1 to counter
        
        blt $t5, $s0, printArray    #branch back to printArray if $t5 = $t4
        
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, newLine
    syscall                 #print new line
    leave:
        jr $ra
```

Comment: _"I have a byte array with a size of 32"_ No, you have a byte array consisting of a single element with the value 32. If you wanted to statically allocate 32 bytes of space, use `.space` instead of `.byte`.

Comment: Use the simulator to check the address of `array` and `array2`.